# Do Classes Inherited from Abstract Classes require methods having the same signature?

Tags: c#, inheritance, abstract-class

I'm a bit confused at some code I recently came across. Here is a snippet. First of the Abstract Class Definition and then of the Class that inherits from it:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    protected static void MapEntityToModel(string paramOne, List<TypeDef> types)
    {
        // Some Logic Here
    }
    protected static void MapModelToEntity(ModelType model, ResultType result)
    {
        // Some Logic Here
    }
} 

public class BaseExtension : BaseClass
{
    public static ViewModel MapModelToViewModel(Model m)
    {
        var result = new ViewModel();
        // Some Logic Here
        return result;
    }
    public static List<ViewModel> MapModelsToViewModels(List<TModel> models)
    {
        return models.Select(m => MapModelToViewModel(m)).ToList();
    }

    public static Model MapViewModelToModel(ViewModel v)
    {
        var result = new Model();
        // Some Logic Here
        return result;
    }
}
```

So my understanding and usage of an Abstract Class has always been that any abstract methods within an Abstract Class must be overridden in the inherited Classes. If a method within an Abstract Class is not declared abstract, the derived Class can create an instance of itself within a method and directly call the non-abstract method of the Abstract Class.

But in either case the methods of the Abstract Class are used in the Derived Class. However, given the previous code snippets the Derived Class has no directly mapped signature or usage.

What then is the purpose of the Abstract Class in this particular scenario and why does it compile without error? I obviously am missing some concept of the Abstract Class and its appropriate implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So my understanding and usage of an Abstract Class has always been that any abstract methods within an Abstract Class must be overridden in the inherited Classes

That is true, but the methods are not abstract, they are concrete (and static).  Only virtual or abstract instance methods can be overridden.

> What then is the purpose of the Abstract Class in this particular scenario and why does it compile without error?

Since the class has no abstract methods or properties I do not see why it is abstract, other than the author doesn't instances created for some reason.

Comment: the methods shown are also static, so cannot be overridden as they exist on the type, not the instance.

Comment: D Stanley - Your first comment seems in agreement with what I stated but you say No?? Maybe you misread my comment or am I missing something? "any abstract methods within an Abstract Class must be overridden in the inherited Classes"

Comment: That is true, but the methods are not abstract, so they don't need to be overridden (and can't because they are both concrete and static)

Comment: Great, so I am not off track on questioning why an Abstract Class is being used in this scenario and I would tend to agree that an Interface may have been a better option if any. Thanks!

Comment: An interface would not work because an interface cannot have an implementation (or static methods).  Making it an interface would _require_ implementers to provide a concrete implementation.

Comment: that is incorrect, you can implement an interface as abstract methods. Much like a class inheriting off an abstract can also implement its methods a abstract and needs to be an abstract itself as a result. The rule is you cannot create an instance of a class that has abstract methods, you can however cast to it - as i illustrated in my answer.

Comment: @JohnNicholas I was referring to the literal `interface` construct in C#, not the _concept_ of an interface, which I agree _could_ be implemented as an abstract base class.

Comment: ahh ok ;) well the too and throw provides a good explanation anyway.

Answer (score 3):

static methods are not part of instances of the class

when you are saying a class is abstract you are saying that you cannot create instances of it.

Abstract on those classes serves no purpose apart from highlighting that creating instances of them is pointless as all methods are static anyway.

Also inheriting from them seems a little pointless as nothing is inherited - all the members are static.
You may as well have only the inherited class and make the base class an empty interface and move the static methods in it into the inherited class (an interface is in effect an abstract class with no method implementations - but you would normally have what are in effect abstract method definitions though)

```
abstract class a
{
    public  abstract string look();

    public static string lookStatic()
    {
        return "look";
    }
}

class b : a
{
    public override string look()
    {
        return "look member";
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(b.lookStatic());
        var test = new b();
        Console.WriteLine(test.look());
        var c = (a) test;
        Console.WriteLine(c.look());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: The base class methods are also protected, meaning that only derived classes can see them.  So the author of the class was probably trying to control access to the methods (though internal would probably be better here, if public was unacceptable for whatever reason).